# Trying to rename filters in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working with SSRS 2K5 and I have some questions that I haven't been able to answer via Google related to Report Builder.  I have built my report and I am using a Model to generate the report. It is my understanding that Report Builder does not support parameters when the underlying datasource is a model so I have setup a filter that the user is prompted to fill in prior to the report being generated no problem.  Here are my two problems:

- The filter in question is a date field.  If I set my filter to do a BETWEEN (date from  to ) there is no option to prompt the user for the values prior to the report being ran.  Is there some way to get around this?
- If I was able to get the above desired date range effect by placing the date field in the filters area twice: once with a condition of 'Before' and the other with a condition of 'After'.  The problem here is how the filters are displayed namely Date and Date 1.  Ideally I'd like these to be displayed as Start Date and End Date, respectively.  Is there any way to do this?

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything or more information is needed.

Comment: What version of report builder you tried? Report builder do support paraments, so why you wrote otherwise?

Comment: I've edited my question.  The Report is being generated from a model and, from my understanding, models do not support parameters.